# unable to create this type of wave motion

Tags: animation, modifiers

I am trying to get this fake smoke effect using wave modifier but it doesn't work properly.
Here is what I'm trying to do
[image]

I tried with wave modifier but it looks like this

[image]

It will be better if someone explain me this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty close to what you want, just rotate the origin a bit on Y to make it more similar to your effect:

[image]

First thing create a shape like that:

[image]

Weight paint the bottom so that it won’t move:

[image]

Choose a motion on X only (or Y, depending on your object orientation), enable *Along Normals* if you don’t want the effect to only happen on Z, *Height* is the height of the wave (how tall they are between bottom and top), *Width* is how big they are, *Narrowness* is how round or sharp they are, choose the vertex group, put a negative *Offset* if you want the waves to begin before frame 1, increase or decrease the *Speed* depending on how fast you want the waves to go:

[image]

Comment: Very elegant! Nice! +1

Comment: thanks, you had a good idea too

Comment: It solved my problem , Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The effect that you are trying to achieve is more complex than one might think at first glance. Your result with the Wave Modifier is already quite good! Unfortunately, it is very limited when it comes to customizing the dynamic shapes of the wave.

You could try a Curve Modifier instead:
[image]
Your smoke cloud will be deformed along a pre-defined (or even animated dynamic) path. I only did a very rough test with a *Nurbs Sphere* and a *Nurbs Path*, and it definitely needs a lot of tweaking, but it might be a way for you to get better control over the shape of the cloud.